# Create exchange certificate from linux CA

Tags: exchange, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I am setting up exchange 2013 in a lab, where we are trying to replace Windows hosts with Linux hosts.  We have exchange up and running, but connections complain that we need a valid certificate.

I've done this from a Windows CA before, but never from Linux.  Can we use Linux to generate the certificates (in the right formats) needed by Exchange?  Or do we need to add cert services to one of the windows servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes - with some caveats.  You must you a linux CA tool that adds CRL's to the certificates.  (TinyCA does not).  Next you do need to import the root ca cert into the Exchange server, then generate a request from the exchange server, and import the response certificate.

After that works great!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to add certificate services.

You just need a ssl certificate that is intended to server usage (like for any other server usage like a webserver or nginx) and use this on the IIS bindings that are seen by the clients.

On the client side it's required that the clients trust the CA that generates the certificates - otherwise you'll get some issues on outlook (like prompting for passwords on every startup).

You do not need to assign new certificates to the backend services of the exchange servers.

If you're using some kind of reverse proxy for exchange, make sure to meet the requirements and limits for exchange (like there's currently no HTTP/2 support and so on - which may be relevant when using nginx).

Comment: Ok - I got as far as importing my self signed cert (and my own CA cert).  Now exchange shows Revocation Check Failed.  I've read a few links relating to proxy settings but they don't apply (confirmed none set).  I used TinyCA and can export a CRL, but how do I get it into exchange?  (And do I need to get it into any outlook clients too)